# Swapping the array of object values

Tags: javascript

I have a simple array of object like given below, I want to swap the order value between two objects.

```
     [
      { 
        id: "one", 
        cmp: "StatsTiles", 
        title: "StatsTiles", 
        order: 3 },
      {
        id: "two",
        cmp: "DeveloperProfile",
        title: `DeveloperProfile`,
        order: 1,
            },
          ]
```

Comment: `const t = arr[0].order;` then `arr[0].order = arr[1].order;` and `arr[1].order = t;`

Comment: which 2 objects? do you need a function that taken 2 generic objects just swaps the value of their order property?

Comment: @Fraction OP does not want to swap array elements, as far as I understand. The array seems incidental here, this is just swapping two variable values.

Comment: I want to do it in useState, It contains my array of objects and I want to update or swap element  using setState function.

Answer (score 0):

```
const swapOrders = (arr) => {
    const orders = arr.map(e => e.order).reverse();
    return arr.map((e, i) => ({...e, order: orders[i] }))
}
```